# summing second columns of all files in bash

Tags: bash, sum

I have 1-N files in this format:

file 1:

```
1 1
2 5
3 0
4 0
5 0
```

file 2:

```
1 5
2 1
3 0
4 0
5 1
```

As an output, I want to sum all second columns of all files, so the output looks like this:

output:

```
1 6
2 6
3 0
4 0
5 1
```

Thanks a lot.

(Alternatively would be the best for me to do this operation automatically with all files that have the same name, but start with different number, e.g. 1A.txt, 2A.txt, 3A.txt as one output and 1AD.txt, 2AD.txt, 3AD.txt as next output)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
cat *A.txt | awk '{sums[$1] += $2;} END { for (i in sums) print i " " sums[i]; }'

cat *AD.txt | awk '{sums[$1] += $2;} END { for (i in sums) print i " " sums[i]; }'
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick summing solution can be done in `awk`:

```
{ sum[$1] += $2; }
END { for (i in sum) print i " " sum[i]; }
```

Grouping your input files is done easiest by building a list of suffixes and then globbing for them:

```
ls *.txt | sed -e 's/^[0-9]*//' | while read suffix; do
   awk '{ sum[$1] += $2; } END { for (i in sum) print i " " sum[i]; }' *$suffix > ${suffix}.sum
done
```

Comment: I am sorry, but how exactly can I use suffix? For example if files are 1LTR.txt, 2LTR.txt and so on.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

suffixes=$(find . -name '*.txt' | sed 's/.*[0-9][0-9]*\(.*\)\.txt/\1/' | sort -u)

for suffix in ${suffixes}; do
  paste *${suffix}.txt | awk '{sum = 0; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i += 2) sum += $i;
                               print $1" "sum}' > ${suffix}.sums.txt
done

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash:

```
declare -a sum
for file in *A.txt; do
  while read a b; do
    ((sum[a]+=b))
  done < "$file"
done

for idx in ${!sum[*]}; do       # iterate over existing indices
  echo  "$idx ${sum[$idx]}"
done
```